# What is the most scenic route from Lucerne to Montreux?

Tags: trains, switzerland, routes, lucerne

I'm looking to travel by train from Lucerne to Montreux in Switzerland.

sbb.ch gives me two main options:

1. Via Bern, in 2.5 hours: [route map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pJgc.jpg)
2. Via Neuchatel, in 3 hours: [route map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxGTE.jpg)

Is the latter significantly more scenic? If not, I will choose the faster route.

Comment: The most scenic route is IMO the golden pass route. Lucerne-Interlaken-Spiez-Zweissimen-Montreux. It is also the longest (maybe around 5-6 hours)

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open because I feel that "scenic" is a clearly defined criterion. "Better" would have been close worthy. Scenic is clearly defined as featuring sights of beautiful nature. If one route passes a bunch of fields, and the other some awesome waterfalls, (I have no idea, don't know the area) it would be objective to say that one is more scenic. I know it's still somewhat subjective, but come on, we're not all machines here. Also, if both (or neither) are scenic and it's a matter of taste, then answers can say that.

Comment: @RedBaron My first thought was also to go through that region but how is the rail link? This route does not even show up on the CFF/SBB route finder...

Comment: @Relaxed On SBB site under advanced search, we can enter intermediate stations and get the route. (Although for this week there is some work on Spiez-Zweissimen line and so a replacement bus service is shown). There are 3 or 4 transfers involved and total time is 5:08

Comment: @Relaxed As for the rail link, it is excellent (like in rest of Swiss), although number of services on Zweissimen-Montreux part is limited.

Comment: I've not gone through neuchatel, but the journey through Bern is just ok, though the destinations are amazing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. Lake Neuchâtel is lovely and you can see it and the vineyards from the train. The line from Bern is just regular Swiss countryside, which is nice enough, and with a bit of luck you might be able to see the Berner Alpen at a distance, but I still think that from the two you listed, Neuchâtel is a clear winner.

Answer (score 3):

The Golden Pass is a train route that starts in Lucerne. Along the way to Montreux you'll see the Brünig Pass, the lakes of the Bernese Oberland, the Simmen valley, upper class Gstaad and Lake Geneva.

Comment: (+1) Information about time, duration of travel and booking could be useful, considering that it apparently does not show up on the SBB route finder (at least not without adding some waypoints).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll look into whether we can afford to spend the extra travel time!